# "sudo: no tty present" for munin plugin using password-less sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, munin, tty

I am writing a plugin for munin to monitor something on our Ubuntu Linux server (which is on Amazon EC2). The plugin requires running a programme `/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl` via `sudo`.

I have the following line in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
munin ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

As you can see the `munin` user (which is the user that runs the script) is allowed execute the command `/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues` via sudo without a password. I have confirmed this works by `sudo -u munin -s` and running it.

However in the munin logs (`/var/log/munin/munin-node.log`), I get lots of output for the plugin like this:

```
2013/06/28-11:35:26 [28107]     sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

And there is no data in the graph.

At the end of my `/etc/sudoers` file, I have this, which is commonly suggested as a solution:

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```

However it doesn't fix it. The common suggestion of "uncomment that line in /etc/sudoers" doens't work either because there isn't anything in that file.

Is there a way to allow my munin plugin to call something via `sudo`?

**Update №1**: The munin plugin is executed by munin-node on the server, that's run as the munin user, I can't change all of munin to run everything as root.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `!requiretty munin`? the order of directives in the `sudoers` file does matter. Also check for include directives.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just run the plugin as root?

Comment: @dawud What order should I put it in? Is that just the line I should put in?

Comment: @EightBitTony everything that doesn't specifically need to be run as root shouldn't be run as root

Comment: Check if there is more than one `requiretty` directive in the `sudoers` file, causing overrides.

Comment: Munin already runs a bunch of plugins as root.  I'm not suggesting running *all* of munin as root, but munin allows you to specify which user each plugin runs as.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to your specific query, but it's a solution to your specific issue.

Rather than using `sudo`, do what other munin plugins do, override the user which runs the specific plugin to be `root`.

More information [here](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/plugin-conf.d).

You add a section like this,

```
[<plugin name>]
user <user>
group <group>
```

to `munin-node` in the `plugin-conf.d` directory (usually in `/etc/munin`).

Several of the munin plugins already run as root, so if you're prepared to run munin, this is already standard practice.